# UWP fullscreen: How to hide taskbar on hover?

Tags: c#, xaml, fullscreen, uwp, uwp-xaml

When you are in "fullscreen-mode" on UWP the taskbar / window header always shows up, when you are touching the bottom / top of the display with your mouse cursor. In the UWP version of Rise of the Tomb Raider a small blue rectangle appears instead, that you have to click to show the taskbar / window header. How can I achieve a similar behaviour in my C#/XAML UWP game? Thanks!

[image: Hidden taskbar]
[image: Hidden image header]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In the UWP version of Rise of the Tomb Raider a small blue rectangle appears instead, that you have to click to show the taskbar / window header.

First I want to say, it is not always a blue rectangle, this rectangle's color is changed along with system's theme.

> How can I achieve a similar behaviour in my C#/XAML UWP game?

You can set the [FullScreenSystemOverlayMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.fullscreensystemoverlaymode.aspx) when your app enters full screen mode, there are two system overlay mode: [Standard, Minimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.fullscreensystemoverlaymode.aspx).

By default in full-screen mode, Standard mode will be used, now you can set it like this:

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().FullScreenSystemOverlayMode = FullScreenSystemOverlayMode.Minimal;
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterFullScreenMode();
```

Answer (score 3):

On system level you can locally disable even "small blue rectangle" by creating DWORD name *AllowEdgeSwipe* in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\EdgeUI
```

and set it to 0.