# Prevent off-screen swipe feature for UWP on Windows 10

Tags: uwp, swipe, taskbar, appbar, commandbar

I have an App that was migrated from Windows 8.1 Store App to UWP.  The original function on Windows 8 permitted a bottom swipe gesture to bring up the `Page.BottomAppBar`.

On UWP (Universal Windows Platform), the bottom swipe gesture now brings up the computer taskbar instead of the App bar.

I understand that I will need to reinvent the swipe feature when I convert the `BottomAppBar` into a `CommandBar`.  But even if I do that, I still need to prevent the taskbar from showing.

Does anyone have any direction on how to prevent Windows 10 UWP default screen swipes?

EDIT
So I did find another issue on stackoverflow that has a slightly similar case.  See [UWP fullscreen: How to hide taskbar on hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37601081/uwp-fullscreen-how-to-hide-taskbar-on-hover).  I'd prefer to completely omit any indicator of the taskbar

EDIT 2
Thanks to @Martin ZickMund, I was able to define an overlay on the page that would allow users to swipe from the bottom of the screen to bring up the `BottomAppBar`, but there is still a small buffer that brings up the taskbar icon in the bottom-center of the screen.

Comment: Can you share your enough codes which you are currently using, for testing purpose

Comment: How about running the app in tablet mode? Set tablet mode in Settings.

Comment: @kennyzx I still see the taskbar when I swipe from the bottom of the screen in tablet mode when in fullscreen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your app is the windowed mode, there is unfortunately no way to implement this behavior, as the task bar will always override your app.

Whent the app is in full screen, this **"might"** theoretically be possible, if you follow similar steps to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32108362/adding-a-swipe-gesture-to-open-splitview-pane) (dealing with left-side swipe instead of bottom).

Comment: So it's like an overlay of the entire app that prevents the OS from acting.  I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Sadly I lack the knowledge to fully comprehend how best to override the OS gestures.  I was able to define an overlay on the page that would allow users to swipe from the bottom of the screen to bring up the `BottomAppBar`, but there is still a small buffer that brings up the taskbar icon in the bottom-center of the screen.

Comment: I am afraid it cannot be overridden from inside of UWP app... It might be possible from a WPF app or if the system was running in the "kiosk" mode. Otherwise however you are better suited having the commands visible on screen. The hiding behavior was deprecated since Windows 10